# Running chrome from the command line and infering when a page finished loading

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, v8

I'm running chromium as follows, making it output generated assembly code and loading a specified .html:

./chrome --js-flags="--print-code" ~/example.html

Is there a way (command line parameter?) to infer whether the page has finished loading, i.e. all assembly code has been outputted? Ideally, by passing this information via stdout.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: no.

One reason is that the statement "the page has finished loading" is so vague that it is effectively not a definition at all. Many modern websites load in stages: at first some server-rendered static HTML is downloaded and displayed, then dynamic content is loaded asynchronously, often again in several steps (e.g., primary content first, ads when idle). What if there are several `<iframe>`s? What if there's a timer on the page that loads more things (e.g., a picture slideshow, notifications, new ads) after X seconds? What if user interaction (clicking, scrolling, etc) triggers more loads? With all these cases, the browser has no way of knowing that "this page has finished", and many pages are never "finished".

Another issue is that the statements "the page has finished loading" and "all assembly code has been generated" are very different things. In fact, V8 generally tries not to compile any optimized code while initial load is still in progress, because that would create slowdowns and jank without providing much benefit. Instead, optimized code is compiled later, for JavaScript functions that are observed to be run a lot. Since optimization depends on what the JavaScript code is doing, there's in general no way to predict whether code generation is finished. I've seen infinite-scroll websites where every scrolling event caused optimized compilation of some more code.

That said, for specific scenarios you can get some approximation: if you have control over `example.html`, you can emit a `console.log("MY_MARKER")` at a time of your choosing. If you then run Chrome with `--enable-logging=stderr`, you can find the `console.log()` statements (along with a bunch of other stuff) on `stderr`.